# How to select the best match in a JPA query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, persistence, jpql

The following query will return the first item (any old item really) where the `like` matches.

```
TypeQuery<Company> query = em.createQuery(
   "select c from Company c where c.name like ?1", Company.class);
query.setMaxResults(1);
query.setParameter(1, "%" + name + "%");
result = query.getSingleResult();
```

However I want the **best** match to appear as my single result.
Here best means the match that differs least from the given `name`.
What kind of `order by` can I apply to this query to make that happen?

Comment: I think you should tag this question with `SQL` to get the help asap.

Comment: The issue is that I know how to do it in SQL, but not in JPQL.

Comment: What about `createNativeQuery()`?

Comment: Then my project will be tied to a single DB, the very thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you please define better the "However I want the best match to appear as my single result."? The best match for a string compare is obtained using the = operator and not the LIKE one.

Comment: *Sigh*, the best match, as in the match that differs least from the argument given in the like parameter.

Comment: You need the SOUNDEX operator, but as far as I know it's not included in the JPA 2 specification, Toplink is the only JPA implementation that offers it, but using its proprietary interface.

Comment: better as for levenshtein distance? how do you do it in plain SQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you need such kind of searching maybe you could use lucene together with hibernate?

See at documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-lucene-api

I think it would be what you need.

Look also at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/-L0LMAScJnA